# What is the unit of getLength() method of com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry

Tags: java, geometry, gis, hibernate-spatial

I am using Hibernate Spatial for developing a Web Application. I have MULTILINESTRING type Geometry and calculating length of the Geometry with geometry.getLength() in the following code snippet:

```
//Returns a Geometry object of MULTILINESTRING type.
Geometry linegeom = routes.oltontShortestPath(oltlat,oltlong,ontlat,ontlong);
double length = linegeom.getLength();
```

Now the question is what is the unit of "length"? How can I get the length in meter?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2155037/1743880?